# Unity jump script isGrounded

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

hello so i have this c#  controller everything is fine but wen i lets say im on a cube high in the air and if i just walk off it not jump it wont do the in air animation and it still thinks its grounded but its not there is nothing to collide with. main problem  wen you walk off the platform it still thinks its grounded
here is the code ;

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float turnSpeed = 50f;
    Animator anim;
    public bool isGrounded;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isGrounded = true;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0);
        anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 0);
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q) == false) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) == false))
        {

            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", -1);
            moveSpeed = 1f;
        }


        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == false))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            moveSpeed = 4f;
        }


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", -1);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 0);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 1);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 0);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", -0.5f);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1);
            moveSpeed = 4f;

            transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {

            anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0.5f);
            anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            moveSpeed = 4f;
        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                anim.SetBool("isGrounded", false);
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 5f, 0f);
                isGrounded = false;
                anim.SetFloat("JumpX", 0.21f);
                anim.SetFloat("JumpY", 0);

            }
        }
            if (isGrounded == true)
            {
                isGrounded = true;
                anim.SetBool("isGrounded", true);

            }


            if (isGrounded == false)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("JumpX", -9);
                anim.SetFloat("JumpY", 0);
                anim.SetBool("isGrounded", false);
            }


            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)))
            {
                moveSpeed = 4f;
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0.1665958f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1.281064f);
            }
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)))
            {
                moveSpeed = 4f;
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", -0.1665958f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1.281064f);
            }
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)))
            {
                moveSpeed = 4f;
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", -0.2470213f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1.281064f);
            }
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)))
            {
                moveSpeed = 4f;
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 0.1665958f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", 1.281064f);
            }
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)))
            {
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", -1.154681f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", -1.005319f);
                moveSpeed = 1f;
            }
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)))
            {
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityX", 1.154681f);
                anim.SetFloat("VelocityY", -1.005319f);
                moveSpeed = 1f;
            }


        }





    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isGrounded", true);
            isGrounded = true;

        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") == false)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: why is there 2 checks for is grounded, and why are you setting grounded to = true in the second one when it is already true

Comment: im really new to most of c# i know the basics but this is kinda hard for me

Comment: Well keep programming things you like you'll get better.  So the question is are you using a jumping animation or are you actually jumping using gravity, are you following a tutorial or winging it?

Comment: Dude the answer is in the duplicated question. Use `OnCollisionEnter` to set `true` and `OnCollisionExit` to set `false`. You simply can't do that only with the `OnCollisionEnter` function like you did in your question. If you don't understand this, please follow [Unity Project tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) before going forward with your game. You will save yourself so much time.